# How to reduce google maps loading time

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I inserted map on my website. I have done everything according https://developers.google.com/web/tools recomendation, but when I checked my page loading speed (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) I got notice „Defer offscreen images" on mobile application ([You can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZPK4.png)). I use defer and async method to load maps, but it does not work. My question is how to reduce google maps loading time? My code snippet:

```
<div id="map" style="border:0; width:100%; height:430px"></div>

<script>
//Map
function myMap() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(55.73657675,21.13070005);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 15};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
  marker.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content:"PERFAS!"
    });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_API_Key&callback=myMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Do you mean *reduce google maps loading **time*** Because reducing loading speed will not improve performance as it will take **longer** to load the map

Comment: @Nicolas OP is a non-native English speaker, so its reasonable that they simply misspoke and that is what they meant.

Comment: @Amy that's what i tought, i just didn't want to remove any useful information if that's not what they meant.